# How did Scott and Spock identify this individual?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

In *TOS: The Cloud Minders*, Spock and Scotty are ordered to teleport the "High Advisor" (a senior planetary government official) from a location in a city to the Enterprise.

The High Advisor gave no consent, he doesn't have a combadge on him and he could be anywhere in the city. **So how did they locate him?**

Comment: Your title didn't really agree with the question. I've made it more specific. I've also taken the liberty of correcting the title of the individual you're referring to.

Comment: Ain't no "com badges" in the original series.

Comment: @Valorum Ok, for the edit of the title, but you reformulate my question too far. I was asking only to the teleport to Enterprise, not the next part with Kirk location.
So I re-edit my question ;)

Comment: @JRE Even more of a reason the High Advisor didn't have one on!

Answer (score 3):

In this instance, they appear to be making an assumption based on the fact that he's hanging around the viewing gallery of the High Council chambers after everyone else has left.

> **SCOTT [OC]:** *I've locked into the co-ordinates of the Cloud City Council Gallery. Ready to transport the High Advisor.*

Note that they materialise him on the platform of the Enterprise *first*, before beaming him to the Captain so there's every opportunity to identify if they've scooped up the wrong person.

Comment: So you assume they search a lonely life form in the council gallery? It's tricky...
They could confuse the High Advisor with his daughter (by the way, they identify her too) when they separate each other. Maybe their life-form detector is very precise and can't confuse them despite the short range.
You're right, they can sort the right person from the wrong on the Enterprise, but in that case, why wait the separation between the High Advisor and his daughter? At that point they (Scott and Spock) already look pretty sure of the identification.

Comment: They couldn't tell the difference between the Advisor and his daughter. They waited until she left. Then he was alone with guards. They would have been lining the walls and waiting at entrances whereas the Advisor would have been free to walk around.

Comment: "why wait the separation between the High Advisor and his daughter?"
I mean, if they're allowed to beam up the wrong person, why wait? They beam up the two of them, resend the girl to the city and the advisor to Kirk.
If they can't precisely distinguish the daugther to the High Advisor, when she left, how they not it's her she left, and not him?

Comment: @GBMan - Their orders were to beam up the High Advisor, not other people in his vicinity

Comment: I trust it was easier than finding spock on a romulan ship. Which  was possible though it took time and effort.

Comment: Not sure. The Cloud City is bigger, more populate, and populated only with the same species. Spock is the only half-human on a single ship.